# Random outputing unintended images

Tags: android

I've seem to run into an annoyance that is probably simple to fix but I just can't figure out how to. The goal is to randomly output two different images whenever the app is opened (Images: mario.png and logo.png). It was working for a long time until I tried to change the app icon (Image: ic_launcher.png) from the default one to a new one (Image: smoke.png) in the Manifest. When I did this, the app would only output logo.png and ic_luancher.png. I tried changing the manifest back to ic_luancher.png but to no avail. Any Ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] Fact;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private int[] picArray = {
    R.drawable.logo,  //This actually outputs
    R.drawable.mario, //This one outputs the defualt app icon although it is not the one I want.
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(225, 151, 51)));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Fact = res.getStringArray(R.array.Facts);
    String q = Fact[rgenerator.nextInt(Fact.length)];
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daily);
    tv.setText(q);

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(picArray[rgenerator.nextInt(picArray.length)]);
    ImageView ptv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ptv.setImageDrawable(d);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:text="@string/edit_message"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/daily"
    android:layout_width="233dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:maxWidth="350sp"
    android:text="@string/daily"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Modifying the manifest doesn't affect the imageview so you must have overwritten the file or something like that. Check your resources folder and try cleaning your project

Comment: Two people have told me to clean out my project, what do you mean <- Newbie

Comment: In Eclipse, Project menu -> Clean